# Is there an equivalent to -ObjC in Xcode build settings for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am currently developing a framework in Swift and in order to use NSClassFromString to perform reflection, the class I'm looking for needs to be loaded.

In Objective-C, I could add -ObjC to the other linker flags in build settings to load the classes at build time and use NSClassFromString, but is there an equivalent for Swift?

Although adding -ObjC works, I'm wondering if there's a different value for loading Swift classes.

Comment: `NSClassFromString` is loading ObjC classes, isn't it? Doesn't matter how you describe their interfaces with Objc of Swift. But Swift was designed to get rid from `-ObjC` flag. Could you describe more yours case when you have issues without `-ObjC` flag?

Comment: Also swift have own reflection: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/debugging-and-reflection

Comment: @Cy-4AH 
I'm sorry for being late. 
If there is a `module B` in `module A`, I am attempting to perform reflection. Therefore, in `module A`, I am trying to retrieve a class without importing the `module B`, using `NSClassFromString` to check if the class exists and then obtain it. However, if the class is not already loaded because I did not use the `-ObjC` or `-all_load` flags, `NSClassFromString` will return nil. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a flag in Swift that can load classes beforehand similar to the `-ObjC` flag.